# Can I have my list tile as first option with null value?

Tags: javascript

So here is my code

```
<select id="BVT STUFF" onChange="jumpTo(getSelected(this));">
<option>HardRock Catalog</option>
<option value="http://link">BVT WIKI</option>
<option value="http://link">BVT CALENDAR</option>
<option value="https://link">Sustainment</option>
<option value="link">UVerse Dispatch Servlet</option>
```

This is a tool that I created for my team.

My problem is that I have the list "Title" as the first option and tried to give it a null value but whenever it is selected it tries to open a page. i.e.  HardRock Catalog

Is there anything I could do with this to allow the list title to really have no value?

Comment: Whats your code for `jumpTo(getSelected(this))`?

Comment: you could use [`<optgroup/>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/optgroup) instead, if you don't want the option to be selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll suggest to add *value=""* for the first option. Then in your *jumpTo* function check

```
<option value="">HardRock Catalog</option>

function jumpTo(url) {
   if(url === "") return;
   // other stuff here
}
```

Comment: oh thanks going to try that. I had
    if (url != null) {
    window.open(url, "_blank");
    }
    }

Comment: This worked exactly as I needed. Thanks so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

You could add `selected` and `disabled` attributes.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s9dYG/)

#### HTML

```
<option selected="selected" disabled>HardRock Catalog</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

**HTML :**

```
<select onchange="jumpTo(this)">
    <option value='0'>HardRock Catalog</option>
    <option value="http:\\google.com">Goto Google</option>
    <option value="http:\\yahoo.com">Goto Yahoo</option>
</select>
```

**JS :**

```
function jumpTo(select)
{
    if(select.value != '0'){
        // code goes here
        location.href = select.value;
    }
}
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6pSep/)